# OnDoubleClick row reactable

Tags: javascript, r, reactable

The documentation of reactable provides a way to define a [custom action](https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html#custom-action) using the *`onClick`*.

```
  onClick = JS("function(rowInfo, column) {
    // Only handle click events on the 'details' column
    if (column.id !== 'details') {
      return
    }

    // Display an alert dialog with details for the row
    window.alert('Details for row ' + rowInfo.index + ':\\n' + JSON.stringify(rowInfo.values, null, 2))

    // Send the click event to Shiny, which will be available in input$show_details
    // Note that the row index starts at 0 in JavaScript, so we add 1
    if (window.Shiny) {
      Shiny.setInputValue('show_details', { index: rowInfo.index + 1 }, { priority: 'event' })
    }
  }")
```

Does reactable provide an `OnDoubleClick` function on a row?

(The [source code](https://rdrr.io/cran/reactable/src/R/utils.R) shows a utils.R file which includes an OnDoubleClick, but the reactable object in R doesn't  seem to expose such a function).

Answer (score 0):

[glin](https://github.com/glin), the owner of the reactable GitHub repository, responded:

Hi, custom actions on double clicks aren't supported, and won't be because double clicking is very uncommon on the web with many accessibility issues. It requires a mouse and is not possible (or very hard) to trigger using a keyboard or touch/mobile device. Adding custom click actions in reactable was already a mistake without providing a way to do that from keyboards, so I'm even more hesitant to add double clicking.

However, you can add double clicking to your table if you render a custom element in your table with a dblclick event handler. For example, here's a column of custom-rendered buttons that run JS code on dblclick events:

```
library(reactable)

data <- cbind(
  MASS::Cars93[1:5, c("Manufacturer", "Model", "Type", "Price")],
  details = NA
)

reactable(
  data,
  columns = list(
    details = colDef(
      name = "",
      sortable = FALSE,
      cell = function(value, index, name) {
        htmltools::tags$button(
          "Show details",
          ondblclick = sprintf("window.alert('double clicked cell %s in column %s')", index, name)
        )
      }
    )
  )
)
```